# Exporting powerpivot data into access

Tags: import, export, ms-access-2010, powerpivot

I am trying to export 5.5M rows from PowerPivot (Excel 2010) into Access 2010 as a table. Do you know how I can do that?
Also, Access has no option of importing data from Powerpivot. I do not have powerquery in excel 2010 that I am using. 
Please Help!!

Answer (score 0):

If you had Excel 2013 you could use VBA to write directly from PowerPivot to Access. And Power Query would give you an easy way alternative of writing the PowerPivot data to Excel sheet in chunks and then you could use Access to import it piece by piece. Power Query is free to download and works with Excel 2010.

Without those I think you should use a flattened pivot table to materialize your PowerPivot data in Excel. Obviously you will have to do this in chunks also because of 1m row limits in Excel and likely resource constaints. So you could add filter and iterate through your dataset. This could be handled by VBA if this was to be a rerunnable process - but it wouldn't be pretty.